# Equivalent of 'profile' as a dimension in Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Supermetrics you can use 'profile' as a dimension to report on a metric across different views/viewIds. Is there an equivalent of this in the Core Reporting Google Analytics api? Or do i have to create a custom dimension?

Thank you

Laura

Answer (score 1):

The google analytics api lets you extract data across a single view or profile.  There is no way to analyze across views.

Technically comparing data across sites would not result in very useful data.  You cant compare two different sites.

Comment: Thak you for that, its useful to know and saved time searching for the solution that does not exist. There is some use in cross-view analysis for example looking at avg server response time across sites.